# Как ковертировать использование обобщения из java в kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть модель на `kotlin`:

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel

class TestModel<V : TestView> : ViewModel() {

    fun attach(view: V) {
        Log.d("testLog", "TestModel - attach() = $view")
    }
}
```

Интерфейс:

```
interface TestView {
    fun showError()
}
```

Есть использующая её `Activity` на `java`:

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;

public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TestView {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TestModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(TestModel.class);
        model.attach(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void showError() {}
}
```

Код рабочий. Как конвертировать `TestActivity` на `kotlin`? Так же пробовал использовать встроенный в `Android Studio` конвертор, не справился.

Comment: Если конвертер не справился, то как еще, ручками :) И осторожно во `ViewModel`, никаких ссылок на активити! Будут утечки памяти.

Comment: Caution: A ViewModel must never reference a view, Lifecycle, or any class that may hold a reference to the activity context.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Comment: @Eugene Ручками и пробую) На счет ссылок на активити знаю, поэтому передаю view, но перепроверю еще. Спасибо.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja ответил. Первый раз не правильно сослался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders

public class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity, TestView {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(TestModel::class.java)
        model.attach(this)
    }

    override fun showError() {}
}
```

Также надо указать тип с которым будет работать метод `attach` так:

```
fun <V> attach(par: V) { }
```

---

Либо так в активити:

```
val model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get<TestModel<*>>(TestModel::class.java) as TestModel<TestView>
model.attach(this)

import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders

public class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity, TestView {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(TestModel::class.java) as TestModel<TestView>
        model.attach(this)
    }

    override fun showError() {}
}
```

И так в TestModel:

```
class TestModel<V : TestView> : ViewModel() {

    private lateinit var view : V

    fun attach(par: V) {
        view = par
        Log.d("testLog", "TestModel - attach() = $view")
    }
}
```

Comment: точки с запятой можно убрать)

Comment: @yno7, действительно)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб так тоже пробовал, вываливается ошибка gradle: TestActivity.kt: (15, 15): Out-projected type 'TestModel<*>' prohibits the use of 'public final fun attach(par: V): Unit defined in *.TestModel'
:app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED

Comment: @iamtihonov, а ссылку на репозиторий с примером для воспроизведения можете дать?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб https://github.com/iamtihonov/TestGeneric

Comment: @iamtihonov, обновил ответ)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо! Вариант хороший. Думаю должен ли я принять ваш ответ как верный или нет, подскажите. Так как в вашем варианте не используются обобщения класса (их можно удалить - class TestModel<V : TestView>), а я их добавлял не просто так, они нужны для обобщенной переменной(https://codeshare.io/5XrrLY) но сильно упростил код (сам виноват).

Comment: @iamtihonov, дополнил ответ)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо)